# Select within a Select returning 0 returns. How to debug?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var items = pSelectedItem.Nodes
                .Expand(e => e.Nodes)
                .Where(e => e.Nodes == null)
                .Select(e => e.Tag as List<ActionObject>)
                .Select(e=> e.Select (i=>i as ActionObject)
                    .Where(i => i != null)                    
                    .Select(i => new ListViewItem()
                    {
                        Tag = new ListViewValue[]
                        {
                            new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Command },
                            new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Target },
                            new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Value },
                            new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Comment }
                        }
}) as ListViewItem);

return new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>(items);
```

The code above, I am trying to capture all listviewitems.  Each list view item has a tag property. This tag property is of type object.

The code above makes complete sense to me however its always returning null. I have tried debugging the code above unfortunately the code above doesn't let me debug the inner select code.  the e.Select (i=>.... is where it won't debug.

Thoughts?  Maybe my code is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: You could split your query in many subqueries, typically one by `Select`, and see which one is failing.

Comment: Looks like the problem you are facing is that the result is not of type `ListViewItem`. But it is an `IEnumerable<ListViewItem>`. The `as ListViewItem` _"does not work. however its always returning null"_ A `Select()` never returns `null`, it would return an empty enumerable.

Comment: Try to remove the `as ListViewItem`

Comment: Do you actually need any of those `as` casts?  As mentioned the last one is definitely wrong.

Comment: Remember the meaning of "as".  It is "*I was unable to write a program that the compiler could determine was type safe, but trust me, this program is type safe, because I know what the type of that thing is; give me null if I am wrong*".  You got null, and so it is highly likely that you are wrong about the type of something.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a shorter way to write "type test followed by null check". The `OfType<T>` sequence operator has those semantics. The `Cast<T>` sequence operator throws if the conversion cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SelectMany` instead, you're currently selecting a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ListViewItem>>`:

```
var items = pSelectedItem.Nodes
            .Expand(e => e.Nodes)
            .Where(e => e.Nodes == null && e.Tag is List<ActionObject>)
            .Select(e => (List<ActionObject>)e.Tag)
            .SelectMany(aclist => aclist.Where(ac => ac != null))
            .Select(i => new ListViewItem()
            {
                Tag = new ListViewValue[]
                {
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Command },
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Target },
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Value },
                    new ListViewValue() { Value = i.Comment }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the SelectMany feature. It seems to accomplish what I need. With some minor tweaks I think it can work. Thanks so much for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

one way to debug is start commenting out Where statements one by one and see if you get results. this will help you in understanding which where clause is causing your results to come back as null. you can go from there.

Comment: The question is how to debug a select within a select. Not how can i comment with good comment practices.

Comment: I am not asking you to add comments, what I am saying is Take one where statement out of your linq first and then see if your query return results. Other option is you can break your linq into smaller linq statements.